# Folder structure differs in magento2 and magento 2.0.2

Tags: magento-2.0

I downloaded magento 2.0.0 by cloning from github. In that the folder structure is like `app/design/frontend/magento/luma & blank`. And every module is defined seperately in luma and blank theme.Now when I downloaded magento 2.0.2 from `https://www.magentocommerce.com/download` the folder structure is different. `root_folder/vendor/magento` contains all the modules and the `frontend` and `adminhtml` are present inside `view` folder. And it is empty inside `app/design/frontend/magento/`. Someone kindly explain where to create the custom theme. Like in 1.9.x we usualy duplicate `rwd/default` to create custom theme. Same way what should be duplicated here and inside which folder it should be duplicated? Someone please explain the concept.

Also at cloned magento 2.0.0 backend when I select `store/configuration->general->design` It is displaying something like `search engine robots` Below is my screenshot[image]

Where to select the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** both version behave the same.
In order to create a theme in `app/design/frontend` in both of the versions.
**Long version.** 
The github version has all the modules in `app/code` because it is more suited for developers that want to contribute to Magento 2.
The downloadable version has the modules in vendor because they are added there via composers.
But the auto-loader looks both in vendor and app code for your classes.

Comment: So can I duplicate luma theme in `app/design/frontend` ?

Comment: I think you can.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge if you will install magento via composer(recommended way) it will store theme in "vendor/Magento/" folder as it is standard way of magento2.

For making new them if you are interested to sell your theme on marketplace than you should create your theme to "vendor/Magento/" (standard way) but if you are making theme for your project use only than you can create it at "app/design/frontend/yourtheme" too.

Reference link For create theme : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have edited my question. can you please explain why that happens?